# Как убрать дублирование кода в унаследованных конструкторах?

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток.

Есть класс `MotiveCalendar` наследуется от `CalendarView`, я переопределил все три конструктора класса `CalendarView`. Пока что используется только одним конструктор, но не суть. В трех конструкторах очевидно дублирование кода. Вот они:

```
private boolean showWeekNumber = false;
private int firstDayOfWeek = 2;

public MotiveCalendar(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setShowWeekNumber(showWeekNumber);
    setFirstDayOfWeek(firstDayOfWeek);
    Log.d( TAG , "MotiveCalendar: Constructor 1 called");
}

public MotiveCalendar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setShowWeekNumber(showWeekNumber);
    setFirstDayOfWeek(firstDayOfWeek);
    Log.d( TAG , "MotiveCalendar: Constructor 2 called");

}

public MotiveCalendar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    setShowWeekNumber(showWeekNumber);
    setFirstDayOfWeek(firstDayOfWeek);
    Log.d( TAG , "MotiveCalendar: Constructor 3 called");
}
```

Параметры календаря определенно будут добавляться и меняться. Думаю можно вынести параметры `setShowWeekNumber(showWeekNumber);`,  `setFirstDayOfWeek(firstDayOfWeek);` и остальные, когда они появятся, в отдельный класс `MotiveCalendarParams`, но не могу понять как мне применить эти параметры потом к календарю не плодя кучу геттеров в конструкторе.

**Вопрос:** Как мне вынести параметры в отдельный класс, или как по другому можно избежать дублирования кода?

Comment: Вынесите дублирующийся код в отдельный метод (например, `init()`) и вызывайте этот метод в каждом конструкторе.

Comment: Либо, по мимо отдельного метода, можно вызывать в одном конструкторе через `this(args)` другой.